# Ajax form within ajax form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The question title might appear strange but it is requirement.

**Scenario -** I have ajax form (MVC4) with a button. Let's name the form as *mainForm*. This button opens popup and this popup also have ajax form (MVC4) named as *childForm*.

*Code Snippet for mainForm*

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserPost", "Admin", null, ajaxOptions, new { @id = "frmUser" }))
{
   ... Code for opening popup
}
```

*Code Snippet for childForm*

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendReminder","Admin",null, ajaxOptions,new { @id = "frmPop" }))
{
  ...Button code
}
```

**Problem -** When I click any button in childForm in Popup, the method for mainForm gets executed.

I am looking for how to guide button click to execute method for childForm only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use an ajax form but just an ajax call in your script

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UserPost", "Admin")',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { id: "frmUser" },
        success: function(result){
            // do something if you want like alert('successful!');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Simple but effective solution. Thanks for saving my night.